# Are the skin depths for an oscillating electric field or magnetic field both the same as EM wave skin depth?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

In the case of an electromagnetic plane wave propagating in free space then incident on a flat metal surface, the electric field induces motion in the conduction electrons (or plasma). If the density is high enough at a given frequency, they will re-radiate a new plane wave back out of the surface. This is one way to understand specular reflection of light (or radio waves) from a metal. At increasing depth the total electric field drops exponentially due to cancellation by the induced current. The characteristic length is called the skin depth.

If instead of the propagating plane wave, the surface is exposed to an oscillating magnetic field parallel to the surface from an inductor, or an oscillating electric field from a capacitive arrangement - in each case there will be a corresponding complementary Lorentz field of the other type (E for B, B for E).

If the coil or capacitive arrangement is small with respect to a free-space wavelength it won't produce a strong enough complementary field to radiate efficiently. (A real-world example would be a near field communication (NFC) inductor in a card-reader or cell phone at 13.6 MHz with a free-space wavelength of 22 meters). In these cases, are the "electric skin depth" and "magnetic skin depth" both essentially the same length as the skin depth calculated for plane wave incidence?